# Reposition UIButtons programmatically

Tags: swift, xcode, button

I have 4 UIButtons in a 2x2 grid, and I want them to move themselves into one column with 4 rows when I toggle a SegmentedControl.

What's the best way of going about this?  Do I need to change the current constraints, or is there another way?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no best way, you can use stackviews and rearrange them or make constraints and change their priorities. you can also calculate positions in container

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `UICollectionViewController`.

On tap of `UISegmentControl` you can change the size of cell under `sizeForItemAtIndexPath()` method based on condition.

Sample Code:

```
class YourViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        if (listViewType == "kTileView") {
            let size = collectionView.frame.width / 2
            return CGSize(width: size, height: 50)
        }
        else {
            let size = collectionView.frame.width
            return CGSize(width: size, height: 50)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean collectionViewController?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want something like this:

[image: demo]

One way to rearrange four subviews from a column to a 2x2 grid is using stack views. Make a vertical stack view for 2-element column of the 2x2 grid, and put those two column stack views in a horizontal stack view. Then, to turn the grid into a single column, you set the axis of the horizontal stack view to vertical.

Here's my storyboard:

[image: storyboard]

And here's my view controller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        updateViews()
    }

    @IBOutlet var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet var rearrangingStackView: UIStackView!

    @IBAction func segmentedControlValueChanged(_ sender: Any) {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
            self.updateViews()
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }

    private func updateViews() {
        if segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            rearrangingStackView.axis = .vertical
        } else {
            rearrangingStackView.axis = .horizontal
        }
    }
}
```